# Linking real clock time to video player time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it was possible to link a getTime() function to a video or a youtube video?

For example, if my clock was at 14:30:02 p.m, my video should play starting at 14:30:02. If possible, how would I proceed to do this?

Many thanks!

```js
function checkTime() {
    if (player.getCurrentTime() >= 20) {
        console.log("Played 20 sec");
    } 
    else 
        window.setTimeout(checkTime, 100);
}

window.setTimeout(checkTime, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your video iframe at a specific time, I don't think you can have any other form of control over an external element.

```css
var thetime = new Date('November 13, 2018 14:49:00')
var msuntillhappens = thetime.getTime() - new Date().getTime();
setTimeout(function(){ 
  console.log("It's time!") 
  $('#frame').html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
  }, msuntillhappens);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="frame"></div>
```

If you want to start a YouTube video at a specific time, you can add a `?start=x` parameter to the frame URL to play a video with a given offset. Depending on what you need, you can get this amount out of current client time or whatever else you need. Other video hosting platforms may have different parameters.

For more information on `Date` object feel free to refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Edit: You can also use [YouTube iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), mix it with the code above and use corresponding API methods instead of inserting iframe html directly.